# Run .exe file from java to convert pdf to Excel

Tags: java, process

I'm searching out for technique to call an exe from Java and passing filepath as parameters and convert it as excel in target folder. How can I do?

```
public static void main(String args[])
{


    try {

        String[] cmd = { "C:/Program Files/Weeny Free PDF to Excel Converter/pdf2excel.exe", "-f E:/PDF/abcd.pdf", "-o E:/PDF1/" };
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);


        System.out.println("success");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

Here Weeny is open souce, i need to convert pdf to excel using this exe. But Im not able to send and convert pdf as excel. I am new to java.
Could someone give me some advice please ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure but shouldn't windows paths be like "C:\...."?

Comment: Does it work in the usual command prompt?

Comment: In command prompt its running without error and weeny is opening, but filepath is not setting as input. with tht i got one more pop-up access denied to weeny.  Now I turn off the UAC.. sory fr late reply

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the path is wrong:

```
"C:/Program Files/Weeny Free PDF to Excel Converter/pdf2excel.exe"
```

There are spaces, which are translated to parameters, not to whole path, so it will try to run

```
"C:/Program"
```

To solve it try to escape spaces like follows:

```
"C:/Program\ Files/Weeny\ Free\ PDF\ to\ Excel\ Converter/pdf2excel.exe"
```

Comment: thank u for valuable reply. But with the earlier path, whn i run the pgm the weeny window is opening properly, but filepath is not adding in it.

Comment: I dont know the parameters it can take, but I agree with @FrankAndreas there are bad slashes, should be `\ ` instead of `/` @KiranP

Answer (score 2):

Correct version:

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try {
            String[] cmd = { "C:\\Program Files\\Weeny Free PDF to Excel Converter\\pdf2excel.exe", "-f E:\\PDF\\abcd.pdf", "-o E:\\PDF1\\" };
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
            System.out.println("success");
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
```

PS: Download some IDE, for example [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/). It can really help you in coding. For example, it automatically convert standard Windows filepath to this correct with double brackets.